# How to enable Element.requestFullscreen on Android WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, webview

When opening my page with IOS `WKWebview` I can use fullscreen in an element by calling `requestFullscreen` directly from the element.

JS

```
var ele = document.getElementByID("myDiv").requestFullscreen()
```

But in order to achieve it I need to enable on my `WKWebView` this preference:
`isElementFullscreenEnabled`

This is all the code that I need on IOS
IOS

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL
        
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webView.configuration.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

My question is how can I enable the same javascript feature on Android(kotlin)?

I tried

```
// Adding a WebView inside AndroidView
// with layout as full screen
AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(it).apply {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webChromeClient= FullScreenClient()

        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true)

        loadUrl(mUrl)
    }
}, update = {
    it.loadUrl(mUrl)
})
```

where FullScreenClient is:

```
class FullScreenClient : WebChromeClient()
{
    val matchParentLayout: FrameLayout.LayoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    lateinit var content: ViewGroup;
    lateinit var parent: ViewGroup;
    lateinit var customView : View;

    fun FullScreenClient(parent :ViewGroup, content: ViewGroup)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    fun OnShowCustomView(view: View, callback: CustomViewCallback)
    {
        customView = view;
        view.layoutParams = matchParentLayout;
        parent.addView(view);
        content.visibility = View.GONE;
    }

    @Override
    fun OnHideCustomView()
    {
        content.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        parent.removeView(customView)

    }
}
```

How can I enable this feature on Android WebView?
What is the Android equivalent way to:

`webView.configuration.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true`